# macCatalyst/ SwiftUI Touch Bar

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst, macbookpro-touch-bar

how could I add Touch Bar Support in Catalyst- Apps written in SwiftUI?

For Example, if I want to display a Button in a View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            Text("macOS")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .focusable()
            .touchBar {
                Button(action: {
                    print("tapped")
                }) {
                    Text("TestButton")
                }
            }
        #endif
        Text("iOS")
        }
    }
}
```

If I use it in a an macOS App it works but if I use it in Catalyst and add targetEnvironment it occurs the error:

'focusable(_:onFocusChange:)' is unavailable in iOS and 'touchBar(content:)' is unavailable in iOS

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom view modifier:

```
struct TouchBarView: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        #if os(macOS)
        return content
                .touchBar { ... }
        #else
        return content
        #endif
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Text("Text")
    .modifier(TouchBarView())
```

Comment: but if I check the OS under Catalyst it returns iOS not macOS

Comment: So, use `#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)`

Comment: then the error appears that it is not available under ios

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
```

to

```
#if os(macOS)
```

`macCatalyst` must still be in the environment for iOS Mac Catalyst apps, so manually checking the OS should be reliable.