# SwiftUI: Can I use Mac-specific modifiers on Mac Catalyst app?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

I'm making a todo-list app available on macOS and iOS using SwiftUI and mac catalyst.
I wondered if it is possible to access **every** modifier available on macOS such as focus, [onExitCommand](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3340135-onexitcommand), without creating a new target (e.g., only using Mac Catalyst). These modifiers are, as mentioned in the documentation, only available on macOS, but can they be used in mac Catalyst apps? And if they are, how can I use them?


I know I can add a touch bar or a toolbar to my application by adding [something like this](https://medium.com/@billibala/swiftui-how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-window-in-macos-app-fc8da5947fe8) to the AppDelegate, but these are specific, there's only a few that can be implemented like that. I tried to follow this [answer's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60638723/13597893) (changing `targetEnvironnment` to `os` and `macCatalyst` to `macOS`), but the Text didn't show up.
Something as simple as this would be appreciated:

```swift
#if targetEnvironnment(macCatalyst)
Text("Hello")
   .onCopyCommand(perform: doSomething())
#endif
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use macOS-only modifiers or styles in a Catalyst app.